# Correspondence between (unkown) programmer pins and ESP8266E leads

Tags: esp8266, iot

I partially opened a smart light bulb, to install [tasmota](https://tasmota.github.io/docs/About/) on it. It is [supported](https://templates.blakadder.com/xiaomi_MJDPL01YL.html) but to flash the firmware you have to connect to the ESP8266E with a programmer. It shouldn't be a huge deal, but ... I cannot find which one of the eight exposed pins go to which [leads in the chip](https://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/1148030/ESPRESSIF/ESP8266EX/5168/9/ESP8266EX.html).

I tried to find continuity with a simple tester. I seems I found the VDDA pin, but since I fail to find GND (underneath the chip) I stopped, because it seems to be connected to more than one pin at once, but briefly, so I'm not really sure what I'm doing.

This is what it looks like now (pins at the back): [image: picture of a ESP8266E on a daughter card]

My chip says ESP8266E and it's on a daughter board that says `E266RPN2 - Wonder llte`.

Somebody totally disassembled theirs and posted the pictures [here](https://remont-aud.net/dump/prochie/prochee/yandex_yndx_00010_shassi_main_board_e266rpn2/363-1-0-127429), it might be easier to see it there. The name of the daughter board is different, but everything else seems to be exactly the same, even the distribution of components on the back side of the main board.

Does anybody know the actual correspondence between the eight exposed pins and the ESP8266E or can suggest a method to find it out?